# android.permission.INTERNET not showing

Tags: flutter

I am trying to deploy a flutter app, but I realized in my androidManifest.xml file I do not have the permission. Anyone would know the reason?

This is the code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hello_world">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="districtFinder"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="t  rue"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare that your app will use the internet with the internet permission inside your Android Manifest.

You can see how to add it to your project [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking)